# Deleting database causes exception until I rename catalog in Web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

If I delete my `aspet-*.mdf` file and then try re-running my project I get this exception

> An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.

the first time it tries to hit the DB. If I then go into my main `Web.config` file and change the "Initial Catalog" bit to a different name and re-run the project, it runs fine.

Why? I'm guessing it's caching something somewhere and it thinks that catalog still exists, but it can't find it?

But I don't have to change the `AttachDBFilename` -- that filename can be exactly the same and it will recreate it as long as I change the catalog.

**What is exactly is a "catalog" and how do I fix this problem so that I don't have to keep modifying my connection string?**

The full string I'm using is

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Sharpix-20120918b;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Sharpix-20120907.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Which is only slightly modified from the one that came with MVC4 application.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your connection string is similar to below

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-123123;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-123123.mdf"
```

1) Using SQL management studio log on to the data source 
     Server Type: Database Engine
     Server Name: (LocalDb)\v11.0
     Authentication: Windows Authentication

2) Once this opens up you will see all the databases that seemingly are being mysteriously created.

3) Right click on the database you want deleted and follow the dialog windows.

The localDB engine, new vof VS 2012, stores all of these development databases. In case you physically delete the .mdf, right click on the database name and delete the database anyway. Ignore the warning message, and then refresh the Databases. The database reference should be gone.

You can do something similar through VS 2012 by selecting View, Server Explorer and then selecting   the SQL Server Object Explorer selection from the Server Explorer pane.